# how can I pass UIColor's name

Tags: iphone, uicolor

I want to know that how can I pass UIColor's name to the specific method ?

EDIT :

```
- (id) setLabel:(NSString *)text WithColorName:(NSString *)nameOfColor FontName:(NSString *)f_name FontSize:(float)f_size abel:(UILabel *)templbl
{
  templbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor ?????];

return templbl;

}
```

any suggestions ?

Thanks..

Comment: I like how you use 3 different variable naming schemes in one method call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSString *colorStr = @"magenta";

NSString *selectorString = [colorStr stringByAppendingString:@"Color"];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
if ([UIColor respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    color = [UIColor performSelector:selector];
}
```

Comment: it's a [selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (id) setLabel:(NSString *)text WithColorName:(NSString *)nameOfColor FontName:(NSString *)f_name FontSize:(float)f_size abel:(UILabel *)templbl color:(UIColor*) myLabelColor
{
  templbl.backgroundColor = myLabelColor;
  return templbl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one option is a dictionary, where the name is the key and the color is the value

Comment: ...or do you really want the string to 'lookup' selectors? in that case, NSSelectorFromString is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically invoke the color class methods:

```
- (id) setLabel:(NSString *)text WithColorName:(NSString *)nameOfColor FontName:(NSString *)f_name FontSize:(float)f_size abel:(UILabel *)templbl
{

    SEL colorMethod = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color", [nameOfColor lowercaseString]]);

    // Check if this is a valid color first
    if ([[UIColor class] respondsToSelector:colorMethod]) {

        // Dynamically invoke the class method
        UIColor *color = [[UIColor class] performSelector:colorMethod];
        templbl.backgroundColor = color;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jhaliya's answer will work, it's not actually strictly what you were asking (in your example you don't want to pass a `UIColor` as a parameter, you just want to pass it's preset string name.

This is a little tricky, since things like `[UIColor redColor]` are methods, not string parameters. You would have to use `NSSelectorFromString` to achieve it. Much better to pass a UIColor in as Jhaliya's answer shows.

Comment: but this method returns UILabel with some properties and I am assigning it to the another label in another file so....