# How do I retrieve named objects denoted by NSStrings?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a set of NSString values like this:

```
self.dataArray = @[@"blue", @"orange", @"green", @"red", @"yellow"];
```

and would like to be able to do something like (after getting one of the above colors set to self.colorString):

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor self.colorString + Color];
```

but obviously can't do that. What is a possible way?

Comment: Sometimes, paraphrasing one's own question would immediately reveal a solution:   `-(UIColor*) colorWithName:(NSString*)name { /* the obvious */}`   ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I pass UIColor's name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804696/how-can-i-pass-uicolors-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **nearly** universal way:

```
NSDictionary *colors = @{
    @"red": [UIColor redColor],
    @"green": [UIColor greenColor],
    @"blue": [UIColor blueColor]
};

NSString *name = @"blue";
UIColor *c = colors[name];
```

A **truly** universal way:

```
NSString *selName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color", name];
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(selName);
UIColor *color = [[UIColor class] performSelector:sel];
```

Comment: @timpone You're welcome. Note that the dictionary method is preferred to the runtime "hackage" one if you know the set of possible colors at compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SEL myColor = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color", self.colorString]);
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor class] performSelector:myColor]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to store associate your data with the colors in a dictionary:

```
UIColor *blue = [UIColor blueColor];
UIColor *red = [UIColor redColor];

NSDictionary *colors = @{@"blue" : blue, @"red" : red};

UITextField *pinga = [[UITextField alloc]init];

pinga.textColor = [colors objectForKey:@"red"];
```

Comment: And how are you going to convert the names into indices? This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks you are right, edited my answer for associating the names tnx