# Get #define of type UIColor from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have defined the following constants, each of which represents a UIColor:

```
// Purple
#define PURPLE_COLOR_DARK  [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.42 green: 0.25 blue: 0.60 alpha: 1.0]
#define PURPLE_COLOR_LIGHT [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.78 green: 0.47 blue: 0.72 alpha: 1.0]

// Blue
#define BLUE_COLOR_DARK  [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.00 green: 0.46 blue: 0.70 alpha: 1.0]
#define BLUE_COLOR_LIGHT [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.00 green: 0.75 blue: 0.88 alpha: 1.0]

// Magenta
#define MAGENTA_COLOR_DARK  [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.75 green: 0.00 blue: 0.28 alpha: 1.0]
#define MAGENTA_COLOR_LIGHT [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.00 green: 0.32 blue: 0.61 alpha: 1.0]
```

**Question**

How can I use an `NSString` like `@"purple"`, `@"blue"` or `@"magenta"` to get the related "X_COLOR_DARK" or "X_COLOR_LIGHT" constant? Is it even possible to do so directly?

**Example**

This is wrong, but should provide a clearer picture of what I'm asking. In this example, I have the string `@"blue"` and want to derive the `BLUE_COLOR_DARK` and `BLUE_COLOR_LIGHT` color values.

```
NSString *color = @"blue";
UIColor *darkColor = (UIColor *)[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@_COLOR_DARK", color] uppercaseString];

// Debugging    
NSLog(@"%@", darkColor); // BLUE_COLOR_DARK
NSLog(@"%hhd", [lightColor isKindOfClass: [UIColor class]]);  // 0
NSLog(@"%hhd", [lightColor isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]); // 1
```

**Follow-Up**

Note that UIColor is not necessarily relevant to answering the question, though it does help for my situation. More specifically, I'm asking if a string matching a defined name (e.g. `@"PURPLE_COLOR_DARK"` and `#define PURPLE_COLOR_DARK`) can be interpreted as the defined name instead of using the defined name directly.

Comment: dont get it at all. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ditch the #defines. And use a `UIColor` category and `NSSelectorFromString` like outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5804789/457406).

Or, create a `NSDictionary` where the keys are the names of your colors and the objects are your colors. You can then get `UIColor` by name.

E.g.:

```
NSDictionary *colors = @{ @"purple_dark"  : PURPLE_COLOR_DARK,
                          @"purple_light" : PURPLE_COLOR_LIGHT };

NSString *colorName = @"purple";

NSString *lightColorName = [colorName stringByAppendingString:@"_light"];
NSString *darkColorName = [colorName stringByAppendingString:@"_dark"];

UIColor *lightColor = colors[lightColorName];
UIColor *darkColor = colors[darkColorName];
```

---

you can't use the #defined names directly because those names don't exist in the compiled code. During compilation the preprocessor will replace all occurrences of `PURPLE_COLOR_DARK` with `[UIColor ...]`

Comment: Having only taken a cursory look at your suggestions, both answers seem promising. I appreciate you explaining that this can't be solved with `#define` directly as well as addressing the incomplete answer below. I'll try out both solutions as soon as I have a free moment and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Your first suggestion to use `NSSelectorFromString` with a category worked wonderfully, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create category of UIColor.

**UIColor+CustomColors.h**

```
+ (UIColor *)redFill;
```

**UIColor+CustomColors.m**

```
+ (UIColor *)redFill
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0 / 255.0 green:36.0 / 255.0 blue:0.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Now use this category in your class:

```
NSArray *color = @[[UIColor redFill], ...etc];
```

[Understand category](https://coderwall.com/p/fqnptq)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for looking at the problem from a different perspective! You'll need to update your solution to fully address my question though ;) In this scenario, I would be trying to derive `[UIColor RedFill]` from `NSString *color = @"red"`. Hence, this solution leaves me in the same boat I'm already in. Also, I'm not thrilled about the idea of ditching `#define` for my project, but I may give it a shot.